# unable to unzip the zip file on linux environment

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am stuck in this issue very badly. I was trying to `unzip` the `zip` file using `java`. I need to upload a zip file using `jsp`. In controller it accepts `Multipart` file. Then I have to `unzip` this file to some location say a `temp` directory. I did `mulipartFile.transferTo('temp zipfile location')`, to place a zip file. Under this location zip file will always be replaced. This (`zipcopy`) would be the source of zip file to be unziped later.. below is code snippet..

```
String zipcopy = env.getProperty("zipFileCopier");
file.transferTo(new File(zipcopy));
```

`file` is of type `Multipart`.

This is running well on windows environment. No issues at all. I changed the path in `application.properties` for `Linux` environment. What I found is -- it is just NOT creating any unziped directories in temp directory. I call unzip code here :

```
unziputility.unzip(zipcopy, destTemp);
File extractedDir = new File(destTemp+File.separator+multipartFileName+File.separator+"local");
if(extractedDir!=null && extractedDir.exists() && extractedDir.isDirectory()) {
System.out.println("TEST");
//business logic            
}
```

`TEST` is not getting printed in `Linux` env. Also note that above code is in `try catch` block with `ex.printstackTrace` method used. However no exception is seen caught. Here is my `UnzipUtility` class:

**UnzipUtility**

```
package abc.xyz.re.util;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class UnzipUtility {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 9096;
    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String entryName = entry.getName();
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entryName;
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
}
```

above `UnzipUtility` when replaced with `lingala zip4j`..same issue. https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j.

**application.properties**

```
uploadDestTemp = /opt/temp

destDirectory = /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/root_/contents/crbt_tones

zipFileCopier = /opt/zip_download/zipfile.zip
```

in above application.properties file, `uploadDestTemp` is already created. Also `zipFileCopier` directory with `zipfile.zip` file is created

I re-tested this case by making sample code only for unziping the zip file from one location to other. Again it ran perfect in Windows. But failed in Linux. code below:

```
package package123;

public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("testing...");
        try {
            UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
            String unzipLocation = "/opt/temp";
            String zipFilePath = "/opt/zip_download/zipfile.zip";
            unzipUtility.unzip(zipFilePath, unzipLocation);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

someone please help me to resolve this issue. kindly tell me why I am not able to use this code on my production Linux environment.

Comment: *I changed the path in application.properties* - what did you change it to?  Also what method is the **TOP** code in?  If `TEST` is mot getting called then then maybe it is not a directory.

Comment: here you are: 

`uploadDestTemp = /opt/temp

destDirectory = /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/ROOT/root_/contents/crbt_tones

zipFileCopier = /opt/zip_download/zipfile.zip`

Comment: application.properties added in question.. pls look

Comment: Make sure that linux user (on behalf of that your code is running) has enough privileges to create files in `/opt/temp` directory

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko all privileges granted sir, with `chmod 777`

Comment: This would be much easier to diagnose if you provided the exception that is thrown (with full stack trace).

Comment: @Henry sorry to mention that late, the code where I call the `unzip` method is already in `try catch` block with `printstack` used in catch

Comment: I hope this issue is faced by many others.. but no one is taking it seriously.

Comment: I assume your machine is Windows and therefore you can't put breakpoints to help you trace what's going on.
My advice is to put a bunch of System.out.println around, logging this way all the paths and other involved variables at each step of execution. This way you'll be able to trace where it's not doing what you would have expected it to do.